# How to remove vibrate effect from the iphone device

Tags: iphone

I am implementing chat application.I have implemented vibrate effect when user get bips.but i want to remove vibrate effect and implement sound effect.how it is possible?

Comment: @Michael: I guess by "bips" he means IM's.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to load a sound file:

```
dingSoundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL( mainBundle,
                                              CFSTR ( "ding" ),
                                              CFSTR ( "caf" ),
                                              NULL
                                              );
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID( dingSoundFileURLRef, &dingSoundFileObject );
```

then play it:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound( self.dingSoundFileObject );
```